# Careers 2.0 latest jobs email with broken links

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, hyperlinks, email

The last e-mail I received from Careers 2.0 has broken links.

Instead of `careers.stackoverlfow.com/jobs/xxxxx/yyyyy` all the urls are `jobs/xxxxx/yyyyy`

Comment: Indeed... We'll fix this.. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for pointing this out - apparently some of the urls we were generating ended up being relative when we didn't want them to be. This should be fixed when we push the new version today.