# Richtext hyperlink missing base URI in Jobs application notification email

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, hyperlinks

I noticed this because an employer replied to their notification of my application (with me as a recipient). My cover letter included a richtext hyperlink to the job listing page (copy-pasted either from GMail or MS Word). The URI is erroneously relative, like so:

```
http://../jobs/######/listing-description
```

Any link in this format will be broken, when trying to use it, in the email because there's no base URI ("careers.stackoverflow.com"). The cover-letter-editor (pop-up that shows when clicking the apply button) doesn't have the full markdown editor (there's only "B[old]" & "I[talics]"). Maybe, as a workaround, hyperlinks should just be stripped altogether.

I don't understand why the base URI is stripped (maybe for flexibility somewhere[?]) but I saved my cover letter elsewhere and it has the base URI, there. I don't know how to test this any further without sending an actual application and/or creating an employer profile.

Perhaps, this is related to the ["unificintegration"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow) (in short, [combining](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314121/why-is-there-a-jobs-site-and-a-careers-site-on-stackoverflow#comment291089_314121) Careers and Jobs).

Comment: Also, maybe related or similar to this issue http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215380/careers-2-0-latest-jobs-email-with-broken-links ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the bug report! It was a long-standing bug with the cover letter editor. It should be fixed now.